# Cancelar los saltos de linea en widget Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Como puedo cancelar los saltos de linea del widget Text?

Lo que intente:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()

textoMensaje = tk.Text(ventana)
textoMensaje.bind('<Return>', lambda _: textoMensaje.delete(tk.INSERT))
textoMensaje.place(x=0,y=30,width=2000)
textoMensaje.insert(tk.INSERT,"Escribe lo que quieras.")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Franco, ¿lo que quieres es que al pulsar Enter no ocurra nada, es decir, que no se agregue una nueva línea?

Comment: Exacto --------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se quiere que la pulsación de <kbd>Enter</kbd> sea totalmente ignorada simplemente debes hacer que la callback retorne la cadena "break". Esto impedirá que el evento se propague:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()

textoMensaje = tk.Text(ventana)
textoMensaje.bind('<Return>', lambda _: "break")
textoMensaje.place(x=0,y=30,width=2000)
textoMensaje.insert(tk.INSERT,"Escribe lo que quieras.")

ventana.mainloop()
```